# Move column_name AFTER Column_name using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to move a column_name AFTER column_name;

I have done the following:

ALTER TABLE tables_name
MODIFY COLUMN columns_name AFTER columns_name;

Any suggestions,

Comment: is there something that you can't accomplish be selecting the columns in a different order?

Comment: Studying for midterms next week and i need to know how to use AFTER in my query's. I was able to complete the query to move my column_name to the FIRST position but cannot get my AFTER statment to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
ALTER TABLE `schema`.`table`   
  CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` INT(11) NULL  AFTER `other_column`;
```

They key here is `CHANGE` instead of `MODIFY` like you have.

Answer (score 0):

I also did this,

ALTER TABLE doughnuts 
MODIFY COLUMN column_name INT AFTER column_name;

I am getting a error under the INT, but the query stills runs and works properly.